# Bokeh Webapp development: live code updates?

Tags: web-applications, bokeh, live-update

I develop a python Bokeh webapp, that i deploy with `bokeh serv webapp.py`.

When i change the code the webapp does not change. I have to shutdown/ restart the webapp manually to see the changes. (Just for clarity: This is not about callbacks to update figures)

Is there a better (smoother) way? As a reference I know plotly/Dash features automatic app update as soon as the python file is saved with changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `--dev` feature was added in April 2019:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/8255

Comment: "April 2020" - in the future? :)

Comment: future indeed. adding the `--dev` flag to the call of bokeh serve gets me a `ERROR: list index out of range` with otherwise smoothly running examples from https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery.html

Comment: @Dr-Nuke I just tested `--dev` with the `examples/app/sliders.py` and `examples/app/crossfilter` examples and it was working perfectly as expected. If you can isolate a reproducible example, you should file a GitHub bug report issue with details.

Comment: @bigreddot i can confirm this works for me. thanks!
probably i had it in the wrong position when i first tried. thanks!
my workflw is now 1) update code 2) save 3) refresh webapp (F5). This is good already.

Answer (score -1):

I found  `bokeh serve --develop webapp.py` according to [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/wiki/Working-Document:-Document-API-and-Bokeh-Server). Sadly, as of March 2020, this is not (yet) supported. They say it is planned for the future. So I guess the answer is no, i have to restart manually to see changes.